# Is there a method in Python to auto convert datetime.utcnow to GMT+7 now?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a proper method to easily converts UTC now time to GMT+7 now time in Python's datetime?

I need to apply this to my db models in Flask.

Here is my `models.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Item(db.Model):
    itemID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    itemName = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    itemPrice = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    itemTimestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item {}>'.format(self.itemName)
```

Any advices would be appreciated.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I can address this issue by creating a new method called `gmt7now()` with the help of `pytz` module, and below is the code:

```
import datetime, pytz

def gmt7now(dt_utc):
    dt_utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow()                                 # utcnow class method
    dt_rep = dt_utc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)                            # replace method
    dt_gmt7 = dt_rep.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Jakarta"))          # astimezone method [gmt++7]
    return dt_gmt7
```